# Import Sent Mail from Lotus Notes to GMail

Tags: gmail, lotus-notes

The company I work uses Lotus Notes (I know, I know), and I have centralized all my accounts including from work to GMail with POP3. I imported everything but the Sent Mail of Lotus Notes and is kind of important because there are a lot of mails in there. I don't have the Lotus Client installed so if I have to access there I use the Web Mail client. What's the best way to import those Sent Mail to GMail? (Installing Lotus Notes client would be my last option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start the IMAP service (if it isn't already started) on the Domino server (`load imap` on the console), enable [imap](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75725) on GMail and then use any imap client to move the mails.